# Superset Period-over-Period Charts

Tags: charts, apache-superset, periodic-processing

Is it possible to create Period-over-period charts in Superset so I can see data for a specified date range compared with data for the same range for another period (year on year, week on week, month on month...)? For example, you might have a period-over-period chart showing your earnings for the previous year side-by-side with the same measurements for earlier years.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'Time Comparison' option under Advanced Analytics.
Refer [here](https://docs.preset.io/docs/time-comparison) on how to use this feature.

[image]